# Can not apply shape to button

Tags: android, android-layout, button

i have a strange issue. I created a simple `Button` which looks like that :

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
android:id="@+id/continue_button"
android:background="@drawable/green_button_selector"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/landing_margin"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/landing_margin"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/landing_margin"
android:text="@string/login_button_text"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

I want to make `Button` green with rounded corners, so I created a xml file called `green_button_selector` and set  is as button background. This file code's is posted below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorGreenButton" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

But instead of my button getting green it has colorAccent of my app, any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: rebuild your project sometime when you make newly drawable it will not add instantly .

Comment: i tried it, but unfortunately it has no effect

Comment: your drawable is working, I think your constraint layout is giving problem. try to set width and check.

Comment: i think margin and width are creating problem.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @RoohAl-mahaba Yes I did, instead of using custom drawable i created a new style extending `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` and applied it to my button. I used `<item name="cornerRadius">@dimen/button_radius</item>` to make corners rounded and `<item name="backgroundTint">@drawable/green_button_selector</item>` to make it green

Answer (score 0):

If  you are using material button you don't need to create custom drawable.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    app:cornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="BUTTON" />
```

[image]

More: https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/outlined_button_label_enabled"/>
```

You can below property for same.

`app:cornerRadius
app:backgroundTint`

Read more from 
[Material Button official document](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)